# Connection reset by peer when sending from hardware (GPRS module) but fine when send from PC

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sockets, embedded

**tl;dr**

- Sending the same data from PC and Quectel GPRS module
- When send from Quectel, server raises an exception `Connection reset by peer`
- But Quectel works in production environment which has the same EC2-micro instance and a load balancer.
- Except for Quectel, another GPRS module - Neoway M680 - works with this EC2 instance.

### Setup

**Local - Setup**
I have a Quectel [M66](https://www.quectel.com/UploadFile/Product/Quectel_M66_GSM_Specification_V1.4.pdf), a GPRS module that I'm using to connect to the server ([AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)) and transfer some data.
I also have a `python script` I've made to connect and send the same data using a PC. Here below is the python script

```py
import socket
import sys
from io import open
from time import sleep

'''
Python script to send data to remote server
'''
#replace address with the remote server address
HOST, PORT = '127.0.0.1', 3000 

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    error = "Error:"
    print("{} {}".format(error, "Pass in the file to be send"))
    exit(1)

filename = sys.argv[1]

with open(filename, "r", newline="\r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = "".join(lines)

# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sock.sendall(bytes(data, "utf-8"))

    # Receive data from the server and shut down
    received = r"{}".format(sock.recv(1024))
    sock.close()

print("Received: {}".format(received))
```

**Remote - Setup**
I'm running an `EC2-micro` instance that's running a python script that just listens to a port and prints the data it received, also send a response which is hard-coded. Here is the script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

'''
Python code running on EC2-micro
'''

import socket
import errno
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

HOST = '0.0.0.0'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 3000       # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            try:
                data = r"{}".format(conn.recv(1024))
                print("Received: {}".format(data))
                #respond back with $E0A0
                conn.sendall(bytes("$E0A0:8B\r$E0FF\r", "utf-8"))
                conn.close()
                s.close()
                break
            except socket.error as e:
                if e.errno != errno.ECONNRESET:
                    raise
                if e.errno == errno.ECONNRESET:
                    printf("Connection reset by peer error again")
                    raise #it is failing here
                pass
```

### Testing

**Quectel GPRS Module**

When I try sending data using the `Quectel` module the using the `AT Commands`, what I see from the hardware (quectel) side is that the connection has been `CLOSED`

```
17:29:05.652 [Tx] AT+QIOPEN="TCP","127.0.0.1",3000\r
17:29:05.672 [Rx] \r\nOK\r\n\r\nCONNECT OK\r\n
17:29:07.699 [Tx] AT+SEND=1\r
17:29:07.718 [Rx] >
17:29:08.603 [Tx] A
17:29:08.647 [Rx] \r\nSEND OK\r\n
17:29:09.446 [Rx] CLOSED
```

And the code running on EC2 crashes with:

```
Connection reset by peer error again
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./server.py", line 22, in <module>
    data = r"{}".format(conn.recv(1024))
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

**But this doesn't happen when I test using the python script** (the first code given above)

**Running python script from PC**

```
$ python client.py data
Received: b'$E0A0:8B\r$E0FF\r'
```

Some more observations:

- This hardware (quectel) is being used in production environment and it works there as expected. Only in this new independent instance (with no `load balancing`) it fails with `Connection reset by peer`
- I learned that this could be because of (from [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/231996/why-do-we-get-the-error-connection-reset-by-peer-d/))

  - Resource limitation at server side
  - High traffic
- But this new instance doesn't do anything else. I have also checked `CloudWatch` and *no spike in CPU usage was seen*.

### Question

1. Do you think this is an issue at the server side?

   - Since the Quectel module responded with `SEND OK`, from the documentation we can be sure that the data has left the module. And TCP promises delivery of data
   - But clearly, before data could be received/read we get `Connection reset by peer`
2. Is it a performance/infrastructure issue?

   - All I could find which sounded reasonable was that the server might be less on memory or other resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a backend issue. A port white-listing issue.